# MySQL CASE/IF usage

Tags: mysql

My application currently connects to MySQL and performs this query:

```
select nickname
from users
where nickname = '$nick' and password = '$pass'
```

`$nick` and `$pass` are inserted by the application.

I need to advance this query to do the following:

- If the `where nickname = '$nick' and password = '$pass'` returns a row just return the row as usual.
- If the `where nickname = '$nick' and password = '$pass'` return 0 rows, I need it to check whether the `'$nick'` is present, and it is the fact that `'$pass'` is wrong that there are 0 rows, if this is the case then return 0 rows, other wise if there is no `'$nick'` in the table, return the row anyway.

i.e. if nickname is in the table and the password is correct, or the nickname isn't in the table, return a row. Otherwise if nickname is in the table and the password is not correct, return 0 row.

Is this possible using MySQL?

Comment: What row should be returned if the nickname doesn't exist in the table?

Comment: @Kenney If it doesn't exist then it should just return the nickname. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select nickname
from users
where nickname = '$nick' and password = '$pass'

union

select '$nick' as nickname
from users AS t1
where not (nickname = '$nick' and password = '$pass') and 
      not exists (select 1
                  from users 
                  where nickname = '$nick')
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/548553/5)

Comment: This is returning 0 rows even when $nick isn't in the table. Test isn't in the table, $nick = 'Test', $pass = '', 0 rows returned. Should return Test.

Comment: @user5603796 Check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/548553/3). User '11' is not contained in the table and yet the query returns one row as expected.

Comment: Doesn't work in real MySQL. mysql> select nickname from nicknames where nickname = 'test' and password = 'pass' union select 'test' as nickname from nicknames where not (nickname = 'test' and password = 'pass');
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: @user5603796 Try to execute just the second part of the query, what do you get as output?

Comment: @user5603796 If this predicate `where not (nickname = 'test' and password = 'pass')` returns an empty set, then this predicate `where (nickname = 'test' and password = 'pass')` should return *at least one* record.

Comment: If I add some test rows, then test, it works. For some reason must be data to work, or it fails. Sorry about that, it works fine once I import some data :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103389/discussion-between-giorgos-betsos-and-user5603796).